# Unable to get into sewer in Stardew Valley Multiplayer even with the key

Tags: stardew-valley

So there is a bug where only me as the host can go into the sewer as well as the desert mine even though it shows both of us having keys in our wallets, but my friend is not able to. Does anyone know why that is?

Comment: Did your friend go into the museum? I haven't yet gotten to that point with my coop buddies but I've read that it's mostly related to who donated the last item and if everyone visited the museum after 60+ items were donated. What's troubling is that you both have the key. Did Gunther give the key to your friend?